# Unable to read MAT file with scipy

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I am trying to read a matlab file using scipy

```
import scipy.io as sio

data = sio.loadmat(filepath)
```

but I get the error

*`ValueError: Did not fully consume compressed contents of an miCOMPRESSED element. This can indicate that the .mat file is corrupted.`*

In Matlab I can open this file without any problem. I also tried to save it again, but nothing changed...
Can you help me?

Here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B3vXKJ_zYaCJanZfOUVIcGJyR0E
you can find 2 files saved in the same way..

I can open part_000, but not part_001.... why? :(

Comment: What matlab file format version are you using?  Try a different,, earlier one.

Comment: it is a normal mat file saved using the matlab command: save(filename)

Comment: among 550 I cannot open only one file.... they were saved together within a foor loop

Comment: So it works for many files, just not this one?  Hard to help without access to the problem file.

Comment: you can download the data from here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B3vXKJ_zYaCJanZfOUVIcGJyR0E?usp=sharing

Comment: I can load part000 without any problem, for part001 I get the error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by the compression. `.mat` files are compressed automatically from version 7 onward.

Therefore, I suggest trying to save the file in the earlier, uncompressed `.mat` file version 6:

```
save(filename, 'data', '-v6');
```

Comment: This just saved me - great suggestion

Comment: I get the same error message as the OP from a mat file that I loaded and then saved with -v6 and that, when inspecting its first bytes, claims to be in MATLAB 5.0 format, i.e., a version 6 mat file.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with `scipy.io.loadmat`'s `verify_compressed_data_integrity` keyword argument, which defaults to `True`. It's trying to do some error checking of the headers, but can raise an error even when the data is extracted just fine. See [this related GitHub issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6999). I'm unsure of the implications of switching this off full-time, but if you use the following, it should resolve your issue in the meantime (I can't check it against your data, it's no longer available at the provided URL).

```
import scipy.io as sio

data = sio.loadmat(filepath, verify_compressed_data_integrity=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can load both files with Octave, and rewrite the one that causes problems

```
>> data1 = load('part_0001.mat');
>> save -v7 part_0002.mat -struct data1
```

In Python the rewritten file loads fine, just like your `0000.mat` file.

```
In [8]: data2=loadmat('part_0002.mat')
In [10]: data2.keys()
Out[10]: dict_keys(['RealTime', 'AccNorm', 'Alt', 'FsP', 'DeviceTime', 'FsA', 'Acc', 'imatemp', 'Time', '__version__', '__globals__', '__header__'])
```

The rewritten file is actually a bit smaller.  A `V6` file is 13M, and also loadable.

```
>> save -v6 part_0003.mat -struct data1
```

So there must be some glitch in `loadmat's` handling of the V7 format.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes the mat files become corrupt, so Matlab cant recognize the data type and unable to load it. so while saving the mat file. try to save the mat file by setting the long_field_names=True

> **scipy.io.savemat(filename,long_field_names=True)**